# Child node is repeating, can't get it to work

Tags: c#, xml

[image]i have an xml code that create an xml file and this works great however i am a bit confused on why one of the parent node still opens and it does not group by employee first ( the employee hours and workdays should only open up once as long as the employee id is the same and close at the end when all days have been created) see attached code `

```
    // Create a new <Employees> element and add it to the root node
        XmlElement Employees = xmlDoc.CreateElement("employees");
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Employees); 
    // Create a new <staffingHours> element and add it to the root node
    XmlElement parentNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("CompanyHours");

    // Set attribute name and value!
    parentNode.SetAttribute("processType", "merge");
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(parentNode);

 string catid = ""; 
string nurseCode = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;    
foreach ( GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    //first part of EMPLOYEES ELEMENTS AND CHILD ELEMENTS
    string fromFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    string toFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    if (catid != row.Cells[0].Text)
    {
     XmlElement employee = xmlDoc.CreateElement("employee");
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(employee);
    Employees.AppendChild(employee);
    //create the element
    XmlElement NurseId1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("employeeId");
    employee.AppendChild(NurseId1);
    NurseId1.InnerText = row.Cells[0].Text;

    XmlElement HireDate1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hireDate");
    employee.AppendChild(HireDate1); 
    DateTime newdate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[6].Text, fromFormat, null); 

    HireDate1.InnerText = newdate.ToString(toFormat);//row.Cells[6].Text;
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(Employees, xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild);

    }

    XmlElement EmployeeHours = xmlDoc.CreateElement("EmployeeHours");

    if (catid != row.Cells[0].Text)
    {
           XmlElement NurseId = xmlDoc.CreateElement("employeeId");
           staffHours.AppendChild(NurseId);
           NurseId.InnerText = row.Cells[0].Text;

   }  


           XmlElement WorkDays = xmlDoc.CreateElement("workDays"); 
           XmlElement WorkDay = xmlDoc.CreateElement("workDay");
            //Third node and data source
            XmlElement Date = xmlDoc.CreateElement("date");
            WorkDay.AppendChild(Date);
            DateTime converteddate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[1].Text, 
            fromFormat, null);
            Date.InnerText = converteddate.ToString(toFormat);


            XmlElement hourEntries = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hourEntries");
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(hourEntries);
            WorkDay.AppendChild(hourEntries);

            XmlElement HourEntry = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hourEntry");
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(HourEntry);
            hourEntries.AppendChild(HourEntry);

            //Fourth node and data source
            XmlElement Hours = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hours");
            HourEntry.AppendChild(Hours);
            Hours.InnerText = row.Cells[2].Text;

            XmlElement JobTitleCode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("jobTitleCode");
            HourEntry.AppendChild(JobTitleCode);
            JobTitleCode.InnerText = row.Cells[3].Text;

            XmlElement payTypeCode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("payTypeCode");
            HourEntry.AppendChild(payTypeCode);
            payTypeCode.InnerText = row.Cells[4].Text;

           staffHours.AppendChild(WorkDays); 
           WorkDays.AppendChild(WorkDay);
           parentNode.AppendChild(EmployeeHours);

           xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(parentNode, 
           xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild);

           catid = row.Cells[0].Text;}
```

now once this code runs it create the attached image but i don't want the highlighted lines repeating inside the same parent node...
[image]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eirsv.png
```

Comment: Shouldn't `XmlElement staffHours = xmlDoc.CreateElement("EmployeeHours");` be before your foreach loop?

Comment: Are you using the XmlDocument for anything else other than writing the file?

Comment: i am only using it for creating and writing the file to send it as an email

Comment: I would recommend using an XmlWriter directly instead of building the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was the element was inside of my loop i needed a new set of eyes to look into this. Good catch Tamas Szabo. issue is resolved.